# How does scdf realize the multi-output function?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Based on the introduction of fan-in and fan out on the official website, I designed the flow model as shown in the figure below:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DynzW.png
The source has two functions to send out hello and mygod string messages respectively. I want to use the destination function of scdf to bind the two functions to different topics, and then be consumed by 2 sinks, but the function that sends out mygod messages Cannot run successfully (scdf cannot recognize the corresponding function).
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This specific case on having multiple inputs to a same app (hello-sink app in your case) isn't supported on SCDF OSS but supported in the commercial version of SCDF. You can find the documentation around this [here](https://docs.pivotal.io/scdf-k8s/1-1/multi-io-support.html)

Comment: did i need to pay for this version?

Comment: ok, i've downloaded this edition, how to cancel it ....